# Change marker in folium map

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, folium

I have a script to plot multiple points on a map through folium. Is there a way to change the shape of the marker and color?

It doesn't matter if it can be done through the python code or the [html file](http://pastebin.com/2jX5j4FR).

```
import folium
import json


map_osm = folium.Map(location=[37.7622, -122.4356], zoom_start=13)

geojson = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPoint",
        "coordinates": [[-122.42436302145, 37.8004143219856], [-122.42699532676599, 37.80087263276921]],
    },
    "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
}

map_osm.geo_json(geo_str=json.dumps(geojson))
map_osm.create_map(path='osm.html')
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Below is how I plotted with dots. I'm actually trying to put together a [notebook of examples (adding color, popup, etc)](https://github.com/collinreinking/longitude_latitude_dot_plots_in_python_with_folium), although I'm still working out the kinks.

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

#create a map
this_map = folium.Map(prefer_canvas=True)

def plotDot(point):
    '''input: series that contains a numeric named latitude and a numeric named longitude
    this function creates a CircleMarker and adds it to your this_map'''
    folium.CircleMarker(location=[point.latitude, point.longitude],
                        radius=2,
                        weight=0).add_to(this_map)

#use df.apply(,axis=1) to "iterate" through every row in your dataframe
data.apply(plotDot, axis = 1)


#Set the zoom to the maximum possible
this_map.fit_bounds(this_map.get_bounds())

#Save the map to an HTML file
this_map.save('html_map_output/simple_dot_plot.html')

this_map
```

You could also use the [polygon markers that this guy shows off](https://gist.github.com/wrobstory/5609786).

Answer (score 2):

You may find it easier to create markers individually, rather than constructing a GeoJSON object first. That would easily give you the ability to style them, as per the example:

```
map_1 = folium.Map(location=[45.372, -121.6972], zoom_start=12,tiles='Stamen Terrain')
map_1.simple_marker([45.3288, -121.6625], popup='Mt. Hood Meadows',marker_icon='cloud')
```

Comment: I just created an example for this question, my actual data contain over two thousands points.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
for i in range(0,len(data)):
folium.Marker([data['lat'][i], data['long'][i]],
          #Make color/style changes here
          icon = folium.Icon(color='green'),
          ).add_to(map_1)
```